# Web compiler for shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny

There are web compiler to run R code like on this website: https://rdrr.io/snippets/. But it is not possible to run shiny apps there. For example, try

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

on the site above and you get the error "createTcpServer: address not available".

Is there a website where we can directly run R code containing shiny apps?

Background: I made a simple shiny app which I want to provide to collegues. Unfortunately, we can not install software (like R) on computers due to security policies of our institution. Therefore, I look for a web compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy any Shiny app for free on [ShinyApps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) for a limited number of hours per month. Deployment can be done straight from R Studio; see the [Documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/).

Comment: I do not think that it is possible to copy paste R code to ShinyApps - there is a bit more involved in the deployment. Do you also get this error while following the example from the documentation I linked above? If so, you might have a firewall that is blocking access. This is something you will need to take up with your network administrator. If there is no possibility of opening up ports, you could consider hosting a local Shiny Server, which is also free. See https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/.